# vb.net reader.read() infinite loop

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

Using While reader.read() going to infinite loop

Trying to get it out of infinite loop

Here is the complete code

```
Dim ConnectionString As String
    ConnectionString = "integrated security=SSPI;data source=SMG-BPCI-DB01;" &
    "persist security info=False;initial catalog=MOSAIC"

    Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    Try
        con.Open()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.ToString())
    End Try
    Dim sql As String = " Select Name, [Description], Type from Tbl; "

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
    Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Export.csv")
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

Dim sep As String = "|"
    Dim builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder

While reader.Read()
        'Get data row by row
        For i = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
            builder.Append(sep).Append(reader(i).ToString)
        Next
        sw.WriteLine(builder.ToString())
    End While
    sw.Close()
    reader.Close()
```

Any thoughts!!

Comment: `using` should be used here. It will GC for you.

Comment: Are you sure it is an infinite loop and not just a very long loop? What's the expected number of rows from `Tbl`.

Comment: May not be infinite loop but there are only 100,000 records but i see the size of the file grows exponentially and i have to stop the process.

Comment: Where do i need to use Using instead of While loop you mean??? not sure

Comment: You need to clear your `StringBuilder` each iteration, or wait till your loop is done to write to the file. Right now you're adding more to the StringBuilder each iteration, and also writing it out each iteration. Probably just easier to write directly to the file instead of having an interim StringBuilder.

Comment: Using is not really relevant to to your problem, but is advisable to use, usually. It wraps up declaration, initialization, and disposal into one construct. Note that it does *not* do anything with the GC. It just simply makes it neater for disposable resources clean up after themselves. See more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx). Your SQL objects and StreamWriter are `Using`-able candidates.

Comment: Did you look at the content of the file? You would see right away that it copies the same rows every time. Clear your stringbuilder or write in the file at the end.

Comment: Thanks Glorin & lotus!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code took care of the problem.

```
builder,clear()
```